# Creating a CTE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a `CTE` in `Oracle` that doesn't select from an existing table but instead has data inserted into it.  Currently, I am creating a table and then dropping it after the `query` is done.  Is there a way to create a `CTE` that effectively does the same thing?  This is my current code:

```
create table RTG_YEARS
(YR date);

insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2013-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2014-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2014-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
insert into RTG_YEARS values (to_date('2015-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can create your common table expression (CTE, [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048), etc.) by selecting the date values from dual, and unioning them all together:

```
with RTG_YEARS (YR) as (
  select to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2013-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2014-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2014-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2015-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
)
select * from RTG_YEARS;

YR       
----------
2013-01-01
2013-12-31
2014-01-01
2014-12-31
2015-01-01
2015-12-31
```

Not related to it being a CTE, but you can reduce the typing a bit by using [date literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062):

```
with RTG_YEARS (YR) as (
  select date '2013-01-01' from dual
  union all select date '2013-12-31' from dual
  union all select date '2014-01-01' from dual
  union all select date '2014-12-31' from dual
  union all select date '2015-01-01' from dual
  union all select date '2015-12-31' from dual
)
select * from RTG_YEARS;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had seen other posts talking about the dual table but I wasn't sure what it was.  This really helps.

Comment: @mosk915 - the documentation about [selecting from DUAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036) explains it a bit.