# Reusing subquery within oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the same query listed as subquery multiple times within a larger Oracle SQL query. Is there a way to define it once and reuse it using a shorter form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of common table expressions.

Copied query from here: [Creating a CTE in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775056/creating-a-cte-in-oracle)

```
with RTG_YEARS (YR) as (
  select to_date('2013-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2013-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2014-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2014-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  union all select to_date('2015-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
)
select *
from RTG_YEARS
cross join RTG_YEARS;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , @Evaldas!