# Reuse Oracle SQL subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to list all items that have cost > average cost. This query works:

```sql
SELECT description, cost, (SELECT AVG(cost) FROM course) as average_cost FROM course 
WHERE cost > (SELECT AVG(cost) FROM course);
```

but I'd like to reuse

```
(SELECT AVG(cost) FROM course)
```

I've tried using `WITH` like some suggested ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631409/reusing-subquery-within-oracle-query)). However it doesn't work.

```
WITH avg_cost AS (SELECT AVG(cost) FROM course)
SELECT description, cost, avg_cost as average_cost FROM course 
WHERE cost > avg_cost;
```

or

```sql
WITH avg_cost AS (SELECT AVG(cost) as avg_cost FROM course)
SELECT description, cost, avg_cost.avg_cost as average_cost FROM course 
WHERE cost > avg_cost.avg_cost;
```

It looks like avg_cost is a table itself.

Comment: You are correct: `avg_cost` is a table itself. As said [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) for `subquery_factoring_clause`: Oracle Database optimizes the query by treating the query_name as either an inline view or as a temporary table. Then you need to use `cross join` with this table to use its columns

Answer (score 1):

CTE (or a subquery) it is, but - not the way you put it. You have to **name** column within the CTE, and then use the CTEs name in JOIN.

Something like this:

```
with temp as 
  (select round(avg(cost), 2) as avg_cost from course)
select c.description, c.cost, t.avg_cost
from course c join temp t on c.cost > t.avg_cost;
```

---

Illustration (sample data from Scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> select round(avg(cost), 2) avg_cost from course;

  AVG_COST
----------
   2073,21

SQL> select * from course order by cost desc;

DESCRIPTIO       COST
---------- ----------
KING             5000    --> King to Clark have their COST
FORD             3000        larger than AVG(COST) from the 
SCOTT            3000        whole table
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450     -->
ALLEN            1600
TURNER           1500
MILLER           1300
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
ADAMS            1100
JAMES             950
SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

Query:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select round(avg(cost), 2) as avg_cost from course)
  3  select c.description, c.cost, t.avg_cost
  4  from course c join temp t on c.cost > t.avg_cost
  5  order by c.cost desc;

DESCRIPTIO       COST   AVG_COST
---------- ---------- ----------
KING             5000    2073,21        --> As expected ... King to Clark
FORD             3000    2073,21
SCOTT            3000    2073,21
JONES            2975    2073,21
BLAKE            2850    2073,21
CLARK            2450    2073,21

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```