# Display only max result from SQL query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
STUDENT.S_ID AS "ID", 
STUDENT.S_LAST ||' '|| STUDENT.S_FIRST AS "Student Name",
COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_NO) AS "Number of courses", 
SUM(COURSE.CREDITS) AS "Total Credits"
FROM 
STUDENT
JOIN ENROLLMENT 
ON ENROLLMENT.S_ID = STUDENT.S_ID
JOIN COURSE_SECTION
ON COURSE_SECTION.C_SEC_ID = ENROLLMENT.C_SEC_ID
JOIN COURSE
ON COURSE.COURSE_NO = COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO
GROUP BY STUDENT.S_ID, STUDENT.S_lAST, STUDENT.S_FIRST;
```

It displays the result:

```
ID     Student Name                    Number of courses Total Credits
------ ------------------------------- ----------------- -------------
JO100  Jones Tammy                                     6            21
MA100  Marsh John                                      5            15
SM100  Smith Mike                                      2             6
PE100  Perez Jorge                                     6            18
JO101  Johnson Lisa                                    5            15
NG100  Nguyen Ni                                       4            12
```

I want only the student(s) with the highest Total credits. For this it would be student with ID JO100. How do achieve this in the query?

Comment: Please provide the Table structure, input data and sample expected output

Comment: If you need to return only top row then have you tried using SELECT MAX(total_credits)...? This will return you  JO100.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.*,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                ORDER BY "TOTAL CREDITS" DESC
            ) AS RNK
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    STUDENT.S_ID AS "ID",
                    STUDENT.S_LAST
                     || ' '
                     || STUDENT.S_FIRST AS "STUDENT NAME",
                    COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_NO) AS "NUMBER OF COURSES",
                    SUM(COURSE.CREDITS) AS "TOTAL CREDITS"
                FROM
                    STUDENT
                    JOIN ENROLLMENT ON ENROLLMENT.S_ID   = STUDENT.S_ID
                    JOIN COURSE_SECTION ON COURSE_SECTION.C_SEC_ID   = ENROLLMENT.C_SEC_ID
                    JOIN COURSE ON COURSE.COURSE_NO   = COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO
                GROUP BY
                    STUDENT.S_ID,
                    STUDENT.S_LAST,
                    STUDENT.S_FIRST
            ) A
    )
WHERE
    RNK   = 1;
```

Comment: does the derived table in oracle not require alias?

Comment: shrek but what if two students have the same total credits?

Comment: Following your query, if two students have the same value it would still bring back the first row, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT 
STUDENT.S_ID AS "ID", 
STUDENT.S_LAST ||' '|| STUDENT.S_FIRST AS "Student Name",
COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_NO) AS "Number of courses", 
SUM(COURSE.CREDITS) AS "Total Credits"
FROM 
STUDENT
JOIN ENROLLMENT 
ON ENROLLMENT.S_ID = STUDENT.S_ID
JOIN COURSE_SECTION
ON COURSE_SECTION.C_SEC_ID = ENROLLMENT.C_SEC_ID
JOIN COURSE
ON COURSE.COURSE_NO = COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO
GROUP BY STUDENT.S_ID, STUDENT.S_lAST, STUDENT.S_FIRST
)
Select Id, "Student Name", "Number of Courses", "Total Credits"
From CTE
Where "Total Credits" = (Select Max("Total Credits") From Cte);
```

Comment: What does CTE mean?

Comment: Common Table expression. **see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL)**  and **[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775056/creating-a-cte-in-oracle)**. I created one, and called it CTE, could just as well have called it anything.

Comment: @RyanThompson, I am curious to know if you had any issues with my answer.