# Unable to find data that is not in my list

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I have a `fruits` table like so

| fruit |
| --- |
| apple |
| banana |

I have this list `('apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange')`. I want to see which which fruits are not in mu `fruits` table. So I expect a result like:

| fruits not in list |
| --- |
| mango |
| orange |

```
SELECT fruit as "fruits not in list"
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit not in ('apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange')
```

Comment: Create CTE (or a temp table) with all values you are interested in, `LEFT JOIN` it with your table and use `WHERE ... IS NULL` to filter out.

Comment: @PM77-1 I unfortunately dont have create table permissions. I can only select

Comment: Then `CTE` it is. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775056/creating-a-cte-in-oracle

Comment: Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2947e6e742960a41204f9581af68502a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list the values explicitly in a derived table.  Then you can use a `left join` or `not exists` or a similar method:

```
select f.fruit
from (select 'apple' as fruit from dual union all
      select 'banana' from dual union all
      select 'mango' from dual union all
      select 'apple' from dual union all
      select 'orange' from dual union all
     ) f
where not exists (select 1 from fruits f2 where f2.fruit = f.fruit);
```